# Load average greater than number of CPUs

Tags: debian, cpu-usage

Why load average is greater than number of cores CPUs? But, htop command is not showing which process are using so much CPU load average.

[image: current load average]

[image: htop command]

Comment: Yes, the load can be larger than your number of CPUs available. And yes, htop DOES show them, see the lower 4 lines in your screenshot. I guess these are sorted by CPU usage.

Comment: LA is affected by blocking I/O and you have at least two processes with `D` state (blocked on I/O).

Comment: Please tag your question with the operating system in question. Load average implementation various between OSes, and performance related tools are very different.

Answer (score 7):

Linux load average is a number equal to the number of the running processes plus a number of processes ready to run and waiting for available CPU plus the number of processes in uninterruptible state (usually blocked on disk I/O). See [Brendan Gregg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Gregg) article [Linux Load Averages](https://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-08-08/linux-load-averages.html) for more details.